My Access front-end is getting a "write conflict" with MySQL as back-end, but not with SQLServer as back-end
I have developed a SQLServer 2016 database hosted by a web hotel, using latest version of Access on my Win11 PC as front-end, connected by ODBC. This works without any error-messages.
I want to migrate a copy of the SQLServer db to a MySQL/MariaDb and use the same front-end.
I have migrated the database to a MariaDb server hosted by the same web hotel, and ensured that the different tables' timestamp field have been set to 'timestamp', 'no nulls', default 'current_timestamp'. Having re-connected using the lates ODBC driver for MariaDB.
All queries/views used by the Access forms are stored in the Access front-end only.
I open the front-end, being the only user. No errors! I open a continueous form based on one table only, and I get an 'write conflict' followed by an Access 3197-error message. The same error-massage appears if I try to run a procedure updating the data. Opening the same table directly in Access 'table view', no conflict. I open the table with an SQL query in phpadmin; no conflict.
I carried out the same exercise, but now migrating the db to a MySQL server on my PC ('localhost').  The same 'write-conflict'-message appears.
I take it that the record locking strategies are different in MySQL/MariaDb and SQLServer.
My question is, what may I do to remedy my problems with respect to using MariaDb/MySQL as server?
Gerhard

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The most common issue is a true/false column that is null. You want to be 100% sure such columns have a default value of 0 (or false, and do NOT allow null values to appear in such columns - else you get the nasty message about how the record been modified by someone else).
Next up, don't confuse a SQL server "timestamp" column with a date/time column.  "timestamp" is the worlds WORST name for a column in SQL Server, and that timestamp column has ZERO to do with time. That column type is a rowversion column. In fact, behind the scenes that column is actually a 64-bit unsigned integer value that simply increments +1 each time the record is updated (hence it has nothing to do with time or date).
The next common issue is use of floating-point columns. Due to the way computers store and save floating values, then rounding errors often will and can occur.
Access to determine changes to a record will thus do a column by column compare with the unchanged row, and since floating point numbers often round and don't compare (for an equal test) then Access thinks the record been changed by someone else.
This means you want to add a row version column (not a date time column) to the table. Access can then use that "row version" column as a test for changes, and Access will then NOT use a column by column compare to determine if the record been changed.
Often, using decimal types, or a currency type for such columns will also fix this common issue.
So, make sure you add a row version column to the database.
As noted, such rowversion columns (called timestamp in SQL server) has nothing to do with a date time value, or some kind of time stamp value.
So, that column type is a real rowversion column. Both .net and MS Access can and will recognize and use such column types to determine record changes. Thus, Access should be able to use that column in place of defaulting back to a column by column compare to determine if the record been changed.
So, null values for date, for datetime, for time, and for text columns should not pose an issue.
For Boolean (or bit) columns, then nulls will pose an issue, and trigger that message. So, ensure that such columns are not null.
As noted, the same often applies to floating point values. Such floating value compares will often fail, and thus introduction of a row version column should fix errors due to rounding compares.
I not used MySQL in a very long time, but I have to assume there is a row version column of some type.  A quick Google shows that the MySQL column is based on time, and that's not what we really want.
You could  thus give MySQL TIMESTAMP column a try but ensure the auto initialize and auto update features are enabled for that column type.
Unfortunately, that is a time-based row version, and thus is less then ideal, but Access should pick that up as a row version column type.
My best guess here is nulls for true/false columns, or that you have floating point column types (real or float).
So, check for nulls in the bit/Boolean column type, and consider using decimal data type columns for those real (float type) values.
I'm not convinced that we can have MS Access use a real row version column type when no such thing exists in MySQL. So, I think solutions come down to ensuring no nulls in those true/false (bit) columns, and using decimal column types for floating values.

I have implemented your recommendations for false/true with 'tinyint', 'not null' and default '0', as well as double/single has been set to decimal. The RowVersion column has been sdet to 'timestamp', 'not null' and default 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. The problem stll persists.

As noted, I don't think Access can use the MySQL timestamp, since what Access needs is a rowversion columh, and MySQL does not have as such.  So, consider removing the timestamp column. Then as test, try adding a new record from Access, and THEN go back and edit that record. If that works, then we still dealing with some type of precision and rounding error. Are there any datetime columns? If yes, add a that new record, and edit any date time, and enter a new value. Now from MySQL workbench, query that one record, and then look at any existing records. Is fraction part of datetime the same?

In other words, if you can add a new record, and go back and edit? But you can't edit existing reocrds? Then this is still some kind of rounding error. Most find that linked tables work fine, but since existing data was imported, then some column is rounding different. That quick test to add and then go back and edit a new record? If that works, then look at any of the datetime columns, and any decimal columns, and note the number of digits. My spider sense guess here is that due to having imported data, then some rounding issue still exists.  So, try a table with the timestamp removed.

So, try the add new record, and then move off record, and then go back to  edit. If that fails, then remove the timestamp column, and test again (add new record, move off and then  go back to edit).  In other words, the timestamp column has the potential to make this worse. Either way, try this add new record in place of trying to edit existing records. If that works, then we know this is a existing data rounding error. As  noted, most don't have this issue, but we have to hunt down what column is causing this. If any datetime columns are being edited in a form, that's one of the first look at

And when I say to look at the fraction part of a datetime, I mean the number of digits after the decimal point . So, you probably need to limit the datetime entry to 1 second resolution - anything more can confuse Access. As noted, this suggests that existing data has different resolution then what Access can see and edit. And as noted, that quick test will tell the story, and such a quick test takes less then 5 minutes of your time. And in this context I am not talking about the attempt at using a timestamp column, but that of existing datetime columns in the database if you have as such.

Your 'spider sense guess' seems to hold water! I removed the RowVersion column, added a new record, edited it with success. Editing an existing (migrated) record created the error message. I tested it on one other table with similar outcomes. So, the problem seemingly stems from the migrated data. However, there is neither date/time nor decimal/double/single columns in any of the two tables.

Well, excellent follow up. Ok, this is in a way good news, since now the issue is existing data, and some "rounding" or compare issue.  Ok, no no floating values. My first and best guess would be a datetime value. But, since you don't have as such, then we back to a true/false column. Open the linked table in design view (ignore the ready only warning), and look VERY close at the data types that Access assumed. And while in design mode, check if the linked table correctly sees the PK column. (I assume a auto number of some type). So, PK is a integer I assume, and a new one created correctly?

I would also open that added record that worked in MySQL workbench (or whatever it is called these days), and look close at the colum values - are they "" strings, or are they null values? I'm thinking along the way here that you either have empty columns as a empty string as opposed to null, or maybe the reverse. So, looking at the added + saved record, and looking at older data - it has to be the true/false values, or null vs empty strings is not being allowed. I apologize, since I don't have MySQL on my current dev computer, so this is me having to guess here somewhat.

Access tables don't require a PK column, but linked tables do. So, check if the table(s) in question have a PK, and that the linked table(s) in design mode sees a PK column.

The PK is seen in the linked table, being an integer column, not auto-increment (which it is in the BE). The true/false columns are seen as integer columns. The null-values in new vs old records are what they should be: Nulls! All tables in the db have integer PKs with auto-numbering. Hope this helps in your investigation!!
